# How can I suggest horizontal rules as good page-breaking points?

Tags: html, css, printing

I'm trying to optimize my pages via CSS for printing from the browser. The problem I'm having is setting up the page breaks properly. I have it preventing page-breaks in the middle of images and blocks of text that shouldn't be separated exactly how I want. However, the problem I'm having is that sometimes there's a horizontal rule separating a new section and then *just* the title of the next section (and potentially a description of that section), with the rest of the actual section displayed on the next page. This is confusing and poor formatting, as normally if the title of the section is that close to the bottom of the page, you'd just throw in a page break before it to bump the whole thing to the next page and not worry about the tiny amount of space on the previous page you're sacrificing.

[image: Page break dilemma]

The HTML here is very simplistic. It's not wrapped in a million things, just a horizontal rule, header, paragraph with a description, then the content of the section. What I tried to do is wrap the header and description in a division together and make it so it can't page-break inside or after, like so:

```
<a id="section_1"></a>
<div class="no-page-break">
    <h2>Section 1</h2>
    <p>Section 1 Description</p>
</div>
<div>
    <!-- all the content for this section -->
</div>
<hr />
<a id="section_2"></a>
<div class="no-page-break">
    <h2>Section 2</h2>
    <p>Section 2 Description</p>
</div>
<div>
    <!-- all the content for this section -->
</div>
<!-- and so on -->
```

```css
.no-page-break { page-break-after: avoid; page-break-inside: avoid }
```

I was hoping it would see the entire block as un-breakable and bump the whole thing down to the next page, but it didn't do anything. Maybe I've just been staring at this problem for too long. Does anyone know how I could prevent each section of my page from breaking up in this manner?

**Note:** I don't want it to *always* break before each section, as that could potentially waste a lot of page space if there's only a little bit leftover from the previous one.

**Bonus:** If anyone knows how you'd be able to hide the horizontal rule if it broke at that point, that'd be helpful too. But that's just a minor annoyance that I'm not really worried about.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of is to move the horizontal rule into the bottom of the last section and before you want the page break. Then wrap all the next section in a node and add no-page-break to that. There are too many factors when printing that the browser just cannot detect so if you can cleverly group things it will help a lot.